# Tortoise SVN 64 bit: proper options are not coming on folders

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, 64-bit

In my previous platform in XP; I checked out files and used to update/commit from there.

Now i switched to windows 7 64bit & also installed from tortoise-SVN 64bit installer.
But, those folders don't have proper icons & most importantly- not getting proper options on right-click.

[image]

The .svn hidden folders & files are present in those directories.

[image]

In XP, its working fine & all required options are coming well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your screenshots: Your working copy has an older version than your [new SVN client](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html):

> Subversion 1.7 introduces substantial changes to the working copy format. In previous releases, Subversion would automatically update the working copy to the new format when a write operation was performed. Subversion 1.7, however, will make this a manual step.
>
> Before you can use an existing working copy with TortoiseSVN 1.7, you have to upgrade the format first. If you right-click on an old working copy, TortoiseSVN only shows you one command in the context menu: Upgrade working copy.

Make sure you read the warnings underneath that paragraph; once you upgrade a working copy, older clients can't access it any more.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot. 1 query- I want to access it also from XP; then I need to install v1.7 in XP also- am I getting it right?